# Preg Replace with mentions

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some problems with the preg_replace.
I would change the mentions in a links but the name isn't a username.
So in the name there are spaces, i found a good solution but i don't know to do it.
Sostantially i would that `preg_replace` the words that are between `@` and `,`

**For example:**

```
@John Doeh, @Jenna Diamond, @Sir Duck Norman
```

and replace to

```
<a href="user.php?name=VAL">VAL</a>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What you want as output? Have you tried something?

Comment: You say replace **between** the `@` and `,` sign. Does that mean you want to keep the `@` sign? Which doesn't really makes sense to me, so therefore this question.

Comment: @user2156006, Post some code, That would be better to understand what you tried? what was the error?. Explain clearly about your input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Based on my assumption you want to remove strings which start with `@Some Name,` in a text like: `@Some Name, this is a message`.

Then replace  that to an `href`, like: `<a href="user.php?name=First_Name">First_Name</a>`

If that is the case then the following regex will do:

```
$str = '@First_Name, say something';
echo preg_replace ( '/@([[:alnum:]\-_ ]+),.*/', '<a href="user.php?name=$1">$1</a>', $str );
```

Will output:

```
<a href="user.php?name=First_Name">First_Name</a>
```

I also added support for numbers, underscores and dashes. Are those valid in a name aswell? Any other characters that are valid in a `@User Name`? Those are things that are important to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want it like:

```
<a href="user.php?name=John Doeh">John Doeh</a>
```

For this try:

```
$myString="@John Doeh, @Jenna Diamond, @Sir Duck Norman";
foreach(explode(',',$myString) as $str)
{
    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $str)) {
        $val=str_replace("@","",trim($str));
        echo "<a href='user.php?name=".$val."'>".$val."</a>";
        // there are spaces
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods:

```
<?php

// preg_replace method
$string = '@John Doeh, @Jenna Diamond, @Sir Duck Norman';
$result = preg_replace('/@([\w\s]+),?/', '<a href="user.php?name=$1">$1</a>', $string);
echo $result . "<br>\n";

// explode method
$arr = explode(',', $string);
$result2 = '';
foreach($arr as $name){
    $name = trim($name, '@ ');
    $result2 .= '<a href="user.php?name='.$name.'">'.$name.'</a> ';
}
echo $result2;

?>
```

Comment: @user2156006 if the answers helped you, try to [accept one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). If you have another question, ask a new question instead of adding an "answer" or edit this one if they resembles.